# Can I run Java EE Spring MVC project without Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have Tomcat installed and it's working when I open a browser.
I want to know that can I run a Java EE Spring MVC project without using Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `.war` file (for example, using `Export -> WAR file`) and deploy it in Tomcat (via web interface of Tomcat Manager or by placing that file into `webapps` subfolder of Tomcat).

Comment: can't i just copy paste the folders

Comment: @Name: I think no, since Eclipse uses different folders for compiled classes and webapp content.